# Dell vostro 5480 Audio doesn't work

Tags: dell, dell-vostro

Dell vostro 5480 in subwoofer does not work anyone knows how to solve.

Comment: Try ` alsamixer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround:

I use Ubuntu 15.04 and the sound from the headphone jack works well, but the speakers are quiet and fuzzy. The solution described below allows you to get a good sound from the speakers, but the headphones do not work then **:/**

You should take the following steps:

1. Install Alsa tools: `sudo apt-get install alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui`
2. Start`hdajackretask` in your terminal
3. In the window that opens, select the codec`Realtek ALC290`
4. On the left side of the window find "Black Headphone, Left side"
5. Tick "Override" and select "Internal speaker(LFE)"
6. Press "Apply now" and test your sound. If all is well, press "Install boot override" and reboot your system.

If you want everything back, then follow steps 2 and all following, but in step 4, uncheck "Override" or press "Remove boot override".

**It's not a permanent solution, but it's something!**

Comment: Thank you for solution, if not enable the subwoofer, but vastly improved sound quality, thank you. I will test ubuntu 15.04 see if it works the subwoofer.

Comment: Worked for me too! Great! Two years of pain without possibility to use laptop fully and now it's finished. P.S.: When I tried to apply changes `hdajackretask` throwed `device busy` error, I needed to stop pulseaudio to solve it - `systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.socket` and `systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.service`, then start it again using same commands, but with `start` argument.

Comment: P. S.: I use 19.04