# Dell Vostro 14 5480 very low volume

Tags: sound, dell, dell-vostro

I've bought Dell Vostro 14 5480 with preinstalled Ubuntu 14.04, reinstalled it to newer 18.10 and faced unpleasant issue - very low volume with bad quality on max settings. First time I see such thing on laptop with Linux and I'm very disappointed. If I plug in headphones - it is ok, good quality, good volume.

Here is alsamixer screenshot - seems that everything related is on max settings:

[image: Alsamixer screenshot]

Comment: This may sound stupid, but are you 100% sure that the issue just isnt poor quality speakers on the laptop? Have you hear them sound better on a different OS?

Comment: Can you try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/663353/344926) first and then report back by leaving a comment @Fabby?  **0:-)** Спасибо.

Comment: @Fabby, thank you very much for this link! It helped me! Two years I've tried to find solution to this problem and now it's done! No one could even realize how I'm happy! Post answer with this link and I'll approve it.

Comment: Пожалуйста!  **;-)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not going to like this as the ***workaround*** below allows you to get good sound from your speakers by allowing the subwoofer, but will disable your headphones:

## :-(

1. Install alsa tools:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui
   ```
2. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

   ```
   hdajackretask
   ```
3. In the window that opens, select the codec `Realtek ALC290`
4. On the left side of the window find `Headphone, Left side`
5. Check <kbd>Override</kbd>
6. Select <kbd>Internal speaker(LFE)</kbd>
7. Stop PulseAudio because if don't, applying settings will fail because of `device busy` (at least it is so for 19.04)

   ```
   systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.socket
   systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.service
   ```
8. Click <kbd>Apply now</kbd>
9. Start PulseAudio again

   ```
   systemctl --user start pulseaudio.socket
   systemctl --user start pulseaudio.service`
   ```
10. Test your sound.
11. If all is well, press <kbd>Install boot override</kbd>
12. reboot your system.

If you want to get headphones back, go back to step 2 and:

- Uncheck <kbd>Override</kbd> in step 5

  or
- Click <kbd>Remove boot override</kbd>.

<sub>[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636326/dell-vostro-5480-audio-doesnt-work)</sub>

Comment: One addition - to apply these changes PulseAudio should be stopped (`systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.socket` and `systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.service`) and then after applying started again. If don't do it, `hdajackretask` will complain on busy device. At least it is so for 19.04.

Comment: **Dmitry** Please feel free to [edit] my answer and put that step right where it belongs...

Comment: +1 for all the <kbd> </kbd> work :)

Comment: @Fabby, done, answer edited

Comment: @DmitriyVinokurov Thank you! Edit approved (so that gave you some additional rep) and then re-edited to allow for better readability. *And look: You're a 100 rep user again already!*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Intel audio SOF driver then you cannot use the hdajackretask to tune pins in order to increase the volume. (hdajackretask works only with legacy intel audio driver).

So, for the Intel audio SOF driver:
Just start "alsamixer" with sudo and you'll see much more volume controls comparing to what you can see if you run it under the non-root user.
Increase the volume of (most of) these levels like Headphone, Speaker, PGA, and the speakers' volume should become louder.